# Checkbox value insert into MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, checkbox

Here is what my front end looks like. I have created checkbox for email on and off, and I would like to store this ON/OFF information in MySQL.

This is my PHP code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Better Check Boxes with jQuery and CSS </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css123/styles.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tzCheckbox123/jquery.tzCheckbox.css" />
<script src="jquery123.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.tzCheckbox123/jquery.tzCheckbox.js"></script>
<script src="js123/script.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="page">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <br>
     <ul>

<li><label for="ch_emails">Email notifications: </label><input type="checkbox" id="ch_emails" name="ch_emails" data-on="ON" data-off="OFF" value="1" CHECKED/></li>
        </ul>

  </form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if(isset($_POST['ch_emails'])){
echo $check=$_POST['ch_emails'];
$sql=mysql_query("Update scott123.rahul_tbl_users set group=$check where Dingoid=$dingo");
if($sql==1){
  echo "Checked";
}
else{
  echo "Not Checked";
}}}
?>
</body>
</html>

### And here is my Javascript code

(function($){
    $.fn.tzCheckbox = function(options){

        // Default On / Off labels:

        options = $.extend({
            labels : ['ON','OFF']
        },options);

        return this.each(function(){
            var originalCheckBox = $(this),
                labels = [];

            // Checking for the data-on / data-off HTML5 data attributes:
            if(originalCheckBox.data('on')){
                labels[0] = originalCheckBox.data('on');
                labels[1] = originalCheckBox.data('off');
            }
            else labels = options.labels;

            // Creating the new checkbox markup:
            var checkBox = $('<span>',{
                className   : 'tzCheckBox '+(this.checked?'checked':''),
                html:   '<span class="tzCBContent">'+labels[this.checked?0:1]+
                        '</span><span class="tzCBPart"></span>'
            });

            // Inserting the new checkbox, and hiding the original:
            checkBox.insertAfter(originalCheckBox.hide());

            checkBox.click(function(){
                checkBox.toggleClass('checked');

                var isChecked = checkBox.hasClass('checked');

                // Synchronizing the original checkbox:
                originalCheckBox.attr('checked',isChecked);
                checkBox.find('.tzCBContent').html(labels[isChecked?0:1]);
            });

            // Listening for changes on the original and affecting the new one:
            originalCheckBox.bind('change',function(){
                checkBox.click();
            });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I tried to write a code like this but the information email ON/OFF is not storing in database. I have created checkbox for email on/off, and I would like to store this ON/OFF information in MySQL, but the value is not getting stored.

Comment: Bobby Tables would love your checkbox. Except he would enter `,password=md5('his-own-password'); select 1 ` in the checkbox this time.

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Hello,I know mysql_* function should not use officially but its the requirement for my project to use old version of php and mysql.Thats why i am using it.Thank You.